# Three-letter words. Or are they longer?

Tags: word, pattern

I was reading a book that my friend had lent me and came across a slip of paper that I supposed was a bookmark. Reading it I saw the following:

DAM

GAS

LOS

NET

NIM

TOR

VIC

WED

YAK

Knowing my friend likes word games and puzzles I tried to see what, if anything, connected the words. In the end I gave up and phoned him.

Him: Oh ha, yes that's just a list of words that I was playing with.

Me: Well I can see that. I wondered why you included LOS. That's Spanish isn't it?

Him: Just read me all the words.

I read them down the phone.

Him: Oh no, all the words on that paper are perfectly ordinary English dictionary words.

Me: Are you sure that the name 'VIC' is in the dictionary?

Him: No, I mean I just cut that bookmark from the edge of a larger piece of paper. I obviously cut through the list of words as well. They were originally longer - all were five letters long in fact.

Me: So what were the original words then?

Him: I think you have now have enough information to work that out for yourself.

Me: Are you sure?

Him: Just find what they all have in common.

**Question**

Knowing that my friend likes words and word-games. What were the original five-letter dictionary words? What did they all have in common?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is clearly "yes".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the words were all originally

> Palindromes!

Which would make the original words:

> MADAM, SAGAS, SOLOS, TENET, MINIM, ROTOR, CIVIC, DEWED, and KAYAK.

Comment: Haha! Much too quick. I toyed with the idea of making it more difficult. I wish I had now!

Comment: You probably shouldn't have distinguished 5-letter words - I got the 5-letter word from 'yak' all too quickly. :)

Comment: I know, I removed that restriction and then put it back!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you could have considered words of different lengths.

Comment: At first I assumed the 3-letter strings were all at the _start_ of the 5-letter words. @chaslyfromUK did you deliberately leave that ambiguous? But there didn't seem to be any 5-letter words starting with NIM, and then I realised what YAK had to be ... and by then Bailey had got the answer :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Bailey's fast...Bailey **real** fast.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica this should probably be accepted as the answer right?